# SOAP UI 5.2.0 Json Path Assertions are disabled

Tags: json, soapui, assertions

When I was trying to validate my REST Json response through assertion in soap ui, I found that the json path assertions are disabled. Is there is a way to enable them in SOAP UI 5.2?

Comment: Assertions you have created are disabled, or the functionality to create new assertions is disabled?

Comment: Functionality to create new assertions on json path is disabled

Comment: Would you like to show the screen shot? And is the expected response in json format?

Comment: JSON Path assertion are disabled when i was trying to create them as a first assertion in my group of assertions. I added Script\Invalid Code assertion and then i can able to add the json path assertions in my testcase.Thank you

Comment: A screen shot if possible?